# python after finished wont exit and release tty

Tags: python

hello this is my script :

```
import sys
import LED
import os

import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LED_BLUE=LED.LED(15)
    if(sys.argv[1]=='1'):
        with open('/home/pi/Work/B','w') as f:
            f.write('1')
        os.system('sudo python /home/pi/Work/Bluetooth.py')
        print '1'
    elif(sys.argv[1]=='0'):
        with open('/home/pi/Work/B','w') as f:
            f.write('0')
        print '0'
```

now when i run this script like this :  `sudo python /home/pi/Work/SetB.py 0`

in terminal print `0` and dont release tty and i need press ctrl + z to release tty

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

`os._exit(0)`

Whenever your process finishes.